# styling is not working with nested routes in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am not able to import the CSS for the nested routes

```
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs') 
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/imgs'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/css"))

app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

const userRouter = require('./Routers/userRouter');
app.use("/users", userRouter);
const basicRouter = require("./Routers/basicRouter")
app.use("/", basicRouter);
```

userRouter.js

```
userRouter.route("/login")
.get(loginPage)
```

if i use this login page with out /users (means with localhost:3000/login)it is working fine but with /users/login it is giving me issue.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it normal your __/users/login__ route is giving an issue? Because there isn't a route like this. And what is relevance between your __/users/login__ route and your css routes ?

Comment: not only specific i just give you an example in all such cases where i have nested routes, i am facing same issues